# Where conditions from two different tables

Tags: sql-server

I running a depreciation database. I need to run depreciation for the next month where two conditions have to be met but from different table

```
insert into Asset.dbo.depreciation (Asset_Tag, depreciation_date, Depreciation_Amount)
   select 
       Asset_Tag, '2012-05-01', Depreciation_Amount 
   from Asset.dbo.depreciation
   where depreciation_date = '2012-04-01' 
   and asset_details.Fully_Depreciated = 'N'
```

The condition after the `and` comes from another table.

Please help

Comment: you are missing join to other table ex: `Asset.dbo.depreciation d INNER JOIN Asset.dbo.Asset_details d2 ON d1.keycolumn = d2.keycolum`

Comment: @rs - write that as an answer before someone else does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing join to other table 
ex:

`Asset.dbo.depreciation d INNER JOIN Asset.dbo.Asset_details d2 ON d1.keycolumn = d2.keycolum where d.depreciation_date = '2012-04-01' and d1.Fully_Depreciated = 'N'`

Comment: Got the Answer <br/> <blink> insert into Asset.dbo.depreciation (Asset_tag,depreciation_date,depreciation_amount)
select Asset.dbo.depreciation.Asset_tag,'2012-05-01',depreciation_amount from Asset.dbo.depreciation join asset.dbo.asset_details on
depreciation.asset_tag = asset_details.asset_tag
where depreciation_date = '2012-04-01' and Fully_Depreciated = 'N' </blink>